# GoogleMap Marker with Picture overlaid on Marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, jquery-gmap3

I am coding a Googlemap Locator system showing your friends, similar to what Apple does with find my friends, However the markers on this system need to have the users profile images as per the visual below.

I am using http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/10-overlays/marker-41 jQuery plugin for the integration which is really just a simple way to integrate the googlemap, but has all the functionality of the API.

I have been reading the documentation for both the plugin and the Google API, however can't seem to pinpoint any way I can do this, I have seen this type of functionality before, so I'm sure it must be possible somehow. Any help on a way I can do this using gmap3 would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I have a solution by using the shadow property for the back pointer and icon for the actual profile image. If that helps anyone else.